# react hooks: patterns when extract hook with callback function parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am extracting a custom hook with a `onRes` parameter;

```js
function useApi(onRes) {
  useEffect(() => {
    api().then((res) => {
      onRes && onRes(res);
    });
  }, [onRes]);
}
```

to use this hook:

```js
import useApi from './useApi';

function App() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  useApi({
    onRes: () => {}
  })
  return (
  <div onClick={() => setX(Math.random())}>{x}</div>
  )
}
```

notice that every time `<App/>` renders, onRes will change, and the useApi hooks will run again

my question is should wrap `onRes` with `useCallback` ? or I just inform the hook users to be careful with this `onRes` parameter ?

```js
function useApi(onRes) {
  const onResCb = useCallback(onRes, []); // should I do this ?
  useEffect(() => {
    api().then((res) => {
      onResCb && onResCb(res);
    });
  }, [onResCb]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This blog post might be useful: [When to useMemo and useCallback](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback)

I would think that using callback is not relevant here since you're not doing heavy computation. `useCallback` would actually be less performant than using the function as-is.

Besides, you can save an API call if `onRes` is undefined.

```
function useApi(onRes) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if(! onRes){
      return
    }
    api().then(onRes);

  }, [onRes]);
}
```

Comment: my point is, every time `<App />` re-renders, like calling `setX`, `onRes` will change, and the `useApi` hook will re-run

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `onRes` from the dependencies array of `useEffect`, this will make sure the effect will run only on mount

```
function useApi(onRes) {
  useEffect(() => {
    api().then((res) => {
      onRes && onRes(res);
    });
  }, []);
}
```

second option, define the function that you pass in with `useCallback` with an empty dependencies array and pass it to `useApi` and keep your current hook the same

```
const onRes = useCallback(() => {
  console.log('hi')
}, []);

useApi(onRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

after reading this article,[Refs to the Rescue!](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/#refs-to-the-rescue), I finally get inspired.

we can store `onRes` with a ref, and call it when needed.

```js
function useApi(onRes) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = onRes;
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    api().then((res) => {
      savedCallback.current && savedCallback.current(res);
    });
  }, []);
}
```